# transformation of a geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

- We have the following geometric sequence $\left(a_{i}\right)_{i \in \mathbb{N}_{0}}$
  So the relation of the neighbouring sequences are as follows: $a_{i+1} / a_{i}=q$
  or: $a_{i}=a_{0} q^{i}$
- Geometric series: $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{i}$
- $k$ -te partial-sum of the geometric series:
  $$
  s_{k}=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a_{i}=a_{0}+\ldots+a_{k-1}=a_{0}+a_{0} q+a_{0} q^{2}+\ldots a_{0} q^{k-1}
  $$
- It is:
  $$
  s_{k}=a_{0} \frac{q^{k}-1}{q-1}=a_{0} \frac{1-q^{k}}{1-q} \quad \text { für } q \neq 1
  $$
  and:
  $$
  s_{k}=a_{0} \cdot k \quad \text { für } q=1
  $$

---

I didn't understand the last two steps of this transformation. Maybe someone can explain.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, consider $qs_k - s_k$.

For the second, partial sum is given by adding the number $a_0$ for $k$ times since $q=1$. However, if $q=1$ then the infinite series does not converge unless $a_0=0$.